# Drawbacks of trimming spaces from _Request, _Post, and _Get?

Tags: php, post, get, request, trim

## Problem

I have an issue on a rather large platform where users can enter data that contains spaces at the beginning and at the end of the input. This causes issues. I know that I can modify the JavaScript validation, but this website has a tremendous amount of pages and forms. Finding and changing each occurrence would be a nightmare.

## Workaround

Since all the forms and pages share index.php, I thought of the idea of intercepting the request/get/post variables before any controller/routing processing is handled by the platform.

Note: I am aware that this is an extremely cheap way of going about it. But actions must be taken immediately until I can at least work on doing it the right way. This is functioning perfectly as it is. I just have a couple concerns.

```
$_REQUEST   = array_map('trim',$_REQUEST);
$_GET       = array_map('trim',$_GET);
$_POST  = array_map('trim',$_POST);
```

## Conerns

1. Are there any actual legitimate scenarios where this code would error on?
2. Is there a major performance hit?
3. Are there any security flaws?
4. Are there risks of data integrity being sabotaged with trim()?

Comment: Just trim the values when you use them.

Comment: 1. When posting array-structured form fields. 2. Not generally, but you can always use a profiler. 3. Unclear; does Unicode whitespace count. 4. Too broad. You haven't let anything on about your data.

Comment: sub-optimial but probably ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I can't think of any. Trim would simply trim leading and trailing spaces of a string. However, it would fail on nested arrays.
2. This, ofcourse affects performance but it's nothing major. Do however note that this is running on each and every single index.php call, even if there was no post data.
3. Trim wouldn't cause security flaws. If you're validating and sanitizing user input in latter pages where you format the data, then there shouldn't be any.
4. I can't answer that question without further knowledge.

If this is only a temporary workaround, then it will do the job. But I wouldn't keep doing this forever and I suggest you fix it field by field when you can.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is **DANGEROUS** and I would **NOT** recommend this.

Here's why:

If there are forms on any of the pages, and those forms contain **password-fields** then users may have chosen passwords that start or end with spaces! *(yes, spaces are absolutely okay in a password, because you are going to encrypt the password anyway)*.

So the problem is:

When you trim all leading and ending spaces from now on then a user who is already signed in with such a password will no longer be able to log in (because every time he tries to submit his valid password (which starts or ends with spaces) your approach is going to DELETE those spaces. Although he NEEDS those spaces to log in).

Furthermore a NEW user who tries to create a NEW account with a password that starts or ends with spaces would never be able to log in EVER. Because he doesn't even KNOW that his password was trimmed.

**So honestly: BE CAREFUL with things like this!**